# Issue compiling examples

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, dlib

I'm trying to compile dlib examples with cmake.
I issued the commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

After some examples are compiled, when compiling the "dnn_face_recognition_ex" example, the compiler never ends compilation.
I cannot figure why. No error shown or log written.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: How do you know it never ends compilation? Maybe it just takes a while.

Comment: Are you using visual studio?  VC has bad C++11 support so some of the examples don't compile or take a really long time. GCC or clang will compile them fine though.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2017. Stopped execution after 3 hours building the same example...

Comment: Provide (in the question post via [edit]) build log near the place when compiling stops.

Comment: What do you mean with build log? Where can I find it ?

Comment: Templates in Dlib are too heavy for Visual Studio compiler. Try using MinGW on Windows. It will not support CUDA, but looks like you do not need training. If you will need it in production, you can make MinGW dll and use it in your project. Also removing one of NN "Level"s will make it compile as the template will be more simple

Comment: Facing same issue, how did you resolve it ?

Comment: Trying with Visual Studio 2015 helped compile dlib.